# How does one delay the evaluation of a template expression in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, transclusion

Not sure if I'm wording this question properly. What I'm trying to do is to write out a template expression in a parent component and delay its evaluation until I can pass it into a child component.

e.g.,

**Parent cmpt**

```
...

<search-results>
  <div>{{ item.title }}</div>
  <div>{{ item.id }} </div>
</search-results>

...
```

**Child cmpt**

```
...
<li *ngFor="let item of data">
  <ng-content select="search-results"></ng-content>

...
```

I don't want the `{{item.title}}` and `{{item.id}}` expressions to be evaluated until the `<search-result>` element is transcluded into the child. How would I go about doing this?

**Update**

There are some hacky workarounds at https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8563, but there is no "right" way of implementing this solution just yet.

Comment: What's the purpose? You don't expect `item` to refer to `ChildCmpt` this way?

Answer (score 0):

```
<search-results #parent>
  <div>{{ parent.item.title }}</div>
  <div>{{ parent.item.id }} </div>
</search-results>
```

Comment: Good idea, hadn't thought of doing something like this. Doesn't seem to be working though.

Comment: It seems the projected content never gets rendered. I tried setting the `isTranscluded` prop to true earlier in the lifecycle just to try it out but to no avail.

Comment: What's the point in delaying rendering anyway? Doesn't make sense to me so far.

Comment: The `<ng-content>` in my code lives inside a `ngFor` directive. Have updated the original post to make this more clear.

Comment: No matter how long you defer the binding, this will not change what class is used for binding. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Added a `#parent` reference but this brings me back to the original issue, it says there is no `item` property as it's trying to evaluate the expression outside of the scope of `ngFor`

Comment: Sorry, didn't see it previously. Using `<ng-content>` this way with `*ngFor` is pointless. Only the first `<ng-content>` element where the selector matches is used, the others are ignored. You might want to use `ngForTemplate`. There are questions and answers already http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bangular2%5D+ngfortemplate